# JIRA: How to get search box to remember project code?

Tags: testing, search, jira, system-testing, uat

I use the search in JIRA about 50 times a day and every time it forgets what I just entered. Is there any way to tell it to remember the last search or the project code. (By project code I mean the first few letters of bug code such as "AAQT-").

Answer (score 2):

That prefix is known as the project key.

(Also, what version of JIRA are you using? There are some UI differences between Cloud and most Server instances so my following advice might not make sense.)

There isn't a way to pre-define the project key in the quick search box since most JIRA instances have multiple projects, and pre-defining it for just one project doesn't make sense.

However, *your browser* should be able to remember previous values entered. You would have to overwrite the numerical portion that follows the key, though.

Comment: It's enterprise JIRA v7.2.8. It never remembers anything. But I doubt I'd have any privileges to alter it anyway. I'm having more success just hacking the url or using the reports feature to find what I need now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean save your search as your favourite filter? If so then you can follow these steps :

1. Click on "Issues" dropdown then choose "Search for issues"
2. Click on "New filter" button on the top-left area
3. Type your query
4. Click on "Save as" button on the above of query field
5. Give any search name, then it will be save under "Favourite Filters" section

Comment: I'll consider doing some of these, but I was really referring to the global search field.